# How to insert only if it doesnt exist in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to update my topics collection with a form in the html.  When i use topics.insert() I can add each document to the collection, but if I use update It does not work.  I want to add the document to the collection only if it does not already exist.

```
Topics = new Mongo.Collection("Topics");

if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.body.helpers({
    topic: function(){
    return Topics.find({});
    }
    });
    Template.body.events({
            "submit .new-topic": function(event){

            //prevent reload on submit
            event.preventDefault();
            //get content from form
            var title = event.target.title.value;
            var subtopic = event.target.subtopic.value;
            var content = event.target.content.value;
            var video = event.target.video.value;

            Topics.update({
                title: title},{
                title: title,
                subtopic: subtopic, 
                content: content,
                video: video
                },
                {upsert: true}
                );
        //clear forms
            event.target.title.value = "";
            event.target.subtopic.value = "";
            event.target.content.value="";
            event.target.video.value="";
            }
            });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"? Does it throw an exception, crash your browser, get sentient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `upsert`.

> Blend of update +‎ insert

```
Topics.upsert({
    // Selector
    title:title
}, {
    // Modifier
    $set: {
        ...
    }
});
```

[See Meteor Docs (collection.upsert).](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/upsert)

Answer (score -1):

I'll give you a broad overview type answer.

First step is you need to check whether or not your entry exists.

```
var collectionEntry = Topics.find({title:title});
```

If you find one, you can update it.

```
Topics.update({title:title},$set{ ... })
```

If you don't find one, you insert it.

```
Topics.insert({ ... })
```

Use the docs here for how to update mongo collections. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Also, you should actually update by the document ID, and you should do this as a Meteor Method rather than updating from the client.

Comment: This seems like quite the overkill when there's something like `upsert`.